# rdesktop: windows server does not answer

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, port-forwarding, rdesktop

I am trying to connect to a RDP Windows server. This configuration works fine in Windows. But not in Ubuntu.

For whatever reason, when using `rdesktop` (or the `remmina` UI), the server does not respond.

I haven't found any question here or elsewhere about the server not responding. There is always an error message from what I can see.

It just timeouts on me after a good while. I seem to be able to connect fine via telnet.

I have to use a proxy. This is what I get:

In the proxy forward terminal:

```
$ ssh -L 3389:target:3389 uuuu@tunnel
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

(NOTE: the error message appears only after a few minutes.)

In another terminal:

```
$ rdesktop -u uuuuuu -d dddddd localhost:3389
Autoselected keyboard map pt
ERROR: Connection closed
```

(The hostname and usernames have been censored.)

Strangely, when using Remmina, the debug window is completely blank.

Is it wrong username? Wrong domain? Wrong options? I just think it is odd that it gives no error. Any help diagonosticating the problem is welcome of course.

NOTE 1: I have used domain name "dddddd" because in the Windows setup, the username is "dddddd/uuuuu". I figured the left part was the domain. In the Windows password, I do not need to give a password before connecting. It says "You will be asked for credentials when you connect.", and a login prompt indeed shows up after connecting.

NOTE 2: I am using a fresh Ubuntu install, so I don't think there's a firewall problem. In fact, I can connect to another Linux server via VNC just fine.

PS: When I do `ssh target`, the command also timeouts with the server not responding. This seems to not be specific to `rdesktop`.